# Passing state and props through React Router

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I'm trying to pass the application state through a react router to to the child components. After several weeks of messing with redux I've come to the conclusion that redux is incredibly convoluted and frustrating to deal with for this purpose. I'm finding myself installing more and more packages to deal with its shortcomings. I tried using redux across the router, only to realize that I now need to install react-redux-router. Then there's the issue with @connect not working in typescript, requiring more "work around" functions and boilerplate. At this point I almost feel like I should just store the values in a hidden input.

Is there not a simple way to pass the application state down through the router? From what I've read this isn't possible in plain react.

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely possible in React. Here's a simple code example:

```
<Route path="/example" render={() => {
    return <Child someProps={someValue} />;
}} />
```